# How do confirm the tomcat process running state from the Java Code

Tags: java

I started the tomcat-8.5 in standalone mode (as a windows process) using **stratup.bat** and I wanted to confirm that the tomcat process is running or not from my java code.
Please suggest me a solution for finding the tomcat process from the java code.

Existing code with java-8: tools.jar

```
  import sun.jvmstat.monitor.MonitoredHost;
    import sun.jvmstat.monitor.MonitoredVm;
    import sun.jvmstat.monitor.MonitoredVmUtil;
    import sun.jvmstat.monitor.VmIdentifier;

    // procName = “Bootstrap”
    /**
    * Confirm startup of server process
    * Obtain process information of JavaVM and check whether 
     specified startup class is running
    * true: Starting / false: not running
    */
    private static boolean checkServerProcess(String procName) {
    boolean blRet = false;
    try {
    MonitoredHost host = 
    MonitoredHost.getMonitoredHost("localhost");
    for (Object processId : host.activeVms()) {
    MonitoredVm vm = host.getMonitoredVm(new VmIdentifier("//" + 
    processId + "?mode=r"));

    if(MonitoredVmUtil.mainClass(vm, true).contains(procName)) {
    blRet = true;
    break;
    }
    }
    } catch(Exception e) {
    blRet = false;
    }
    return blRet;
    }
```

Since the tools.jar is removed in latest jdk, and we want to know the alternative solution for checking the tomcat status.

Thank you

Comment: You should be more precise about which Java version and which JDK you are targeting.

Comment: We migrated to Java-11(AdoptOpenJDK). tools.jar is no longer available in jdk-11 and classes found in tools.jar are now available under jdk.internal.jvmstat module sun.jvmstat.monitor.* packages are not visible to access from out side.